# Passing parameters to an HTTP request from a C class

Tags: c, http, endianness

My problem is difficult to say, but I try.

I have a module, ztc_config, that reads response from some sensors in my net. To read this response, I have written a C class, query.c that's this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "data.h"
#include "modules.h"

void query(hash_t* params) {
    record_t* rec;
    timestamp_t ts;
    timestamp_t rec_ts;
    uint32_t sec;
    uint32_t usec;
    timestamp_t now;
    timestamp_t start;
    timestamp_t end;
    char* startime;
    char* endtime;
    // Coordinator, opgroup and  Opcode  specified by the client
    uint64_t netid = 0;
    uint8_t opcode_group = 0;
    uint8_t opcode = 0;
    char* par;
    now = mdl_now();
    /* set the start and end time based on query parameters */
    startime = hash_get(params, "start");
    if(startime != NULL) 
        start = mdl_parse_timestr(startime, now);
    else
        start = now;
    endtime = hash_get(params, "end");
    if(endtime != NULL) 
        end = mdl_parse_timestr(endtime, now);
    else 
        end = ~0;
    // Network id is required
    par = hash_get(params, "netid");
    if(par == NULL) {
        mdl_print("netid required\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    netid = strtoull(par, NULL, 10);
    par = hash_get(params, "opcode_group");
    if(par == NULL) {
        mdl_print("opcode_group required\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    opcode_group = strtoul(par, NULL, 10);
    par = hash_get(params, "opcode");
    if(par == NULL) {
        mdl_print("opcode required\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    opcode = strtoul(par, NULL, 10);
    /* seek in the bytestream */
    mdl_seek(start);
    while((rec = (record_t* ) mdl_next(&ts)) != NULL) {
        uint64_t val;
        //float fval;
        /* reached end time ? */
        if(ts > end) break;
        rec_ts = NTOHLL(rec->ts);
        sec = TS2SEC(rec_ts);
        usec = TS2USEC(rec_ts);
        // Only print records with the wanted net and opcodes
        if((netid != 0) && (netid != NTOHLL(rec->net_id))) 
            continue;
        if((opcode_group != 0) && (opcode_group != ntohl(rec->opcode_group))) 
            continue;
        if((opcode != 0) && (opcode != ntohl(rec->opcode)))
            continue;
        val = NTOHLL(rec->payload);
        mdl_print("%u %llu %u %u %u %d\n", sec, NTOHLL(rec->net_id), rec->op_code_group, rec->op_code, rec->payloadlength, val);
    }
}
```

I would that when I visit this link for example:

```
http://localhost:44444/ztc_config?netid=2459546910990453036&opcode_group=164&opcode=224&start=-5m&end=-1s
```

in the page I see only record from netid 2459546910990453036
with opcode_group 164 (hex A4)
with opcode 224 (hex E0)
in the last 5 minutes.

But there is something wrong in my query.c class. So if I visit this link

```
http://localhost:44444/ztc_config?netid=0&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-5m&end=-1s
```

I have all the records in the last 5 minutes.

But if I change any opcode_group or opcode value, I didn't obtain anything...

Any suggestions? Where is the error?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

I tried to change the name of the two variables opcode_group and opcode like this:

```
....
uint8_t op_code_group =0;
uint8_t op_code =0;
....
....
op_code_group = strtoul(par, NULL, 10);
....
op_code = strtoul(par, NULL, 10);
```

In this way I write:

```
if ((op_code_group != 0) && (op_code_group != ntohl(rec->opcode_group))) continue;
if ((op_code != 0) && (op_code != ntohl(rec->opcode))) continue;
```

and this should be a filter. In the other case, with the same variables names, the condition was true, but the value was always the initialization value = 0. Or not?

This solution doesn't work anyway... :( please help me!

Comment: I think that's not technically a C++ class.

Comment: I can't see any reference in your code to the `opcode_group` or `opcode` parameters. I assume they're being passed in as `hash_t* params`, are they read somewhere else?

Comment: Yes they are parameters passed in as hash_t* params

Comment: ztc_config is a CoMo module. See here for more informations http://onelab.eu/images/PDFs/Deliverables/d3a.2.pdf

Comment: I pass the parameters in a Python handler, where I make an http request: `como_url = "".join(['http://', options.como_address, ':', options.como_port,
                            '/ztc_config?netid=', int(nid),
                            '&opcode_group=', opcodegroupr, 
                            '&opcode=', opcoder, '&start=-5m&end=-1s']) `